# A thought about caching data on Android

Tags: android, json, api, caching

So i have been thinking of good ways to cache data. Not only images, because if data doesn't change, it is not necessary to fetch that data again. The thing i have been thinking about is :

Lets assume i have written an API in php which gives JSON as an response to requests that are made through my applications on Android and other mobile platforms.

I have a structure where users can see albums of certain companys. The structure is as follows :

- Company
- - Album (Company HasMany Album's)
- - - Photo (Album HasMany Photo's)

One of the functionality of my API is, it can show a list of all company's that we have in our database. That list can be quite big. My approach to cache this data is this :

- Generate an API_CACHE_KEY and when a Company gets edited or removed, i can just compare the API_CACHE_KEY in my sharedprefences with the one from the webserver. If it is different, i will only fetch company's which have changed because i can also fetch individual company's in my API. This API_CACHE_KEY will be based on a timestamp which is hashed.
- If the API_CACHE_KEY is the same as last time, i can just get the data out of my cache.

Would this be a good technique of caching all kinds of data? Or is it overkill to do it like this? I am aware that it takes a request to fetch the API_CACHE_KEY but it would be less data than if i fetch the whole list each time.

What is considered good practice? And do you guys have other smart techniques for handling this kind of caching?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better, from a performance perspective, for the application to store the timestamp and send that? This way the API's server could determine what data to send and you'd resolve the update in a single request.

Comment: Ahh, that would be a nice way of refreshing data where it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would first decide what specific problem you are trying to solve by caching. There are two distinct things I can think of that you are trying to avoid:

1. Making an HTTP call to your service.
2. After having made a call, doing work on the server side (in PHP).

**Self Expiring**

You can avoid (1) by caching data *locally* on the Android device and letting it expire on its own.

Simply make an expensive company API call and then store it locally for something like 6 hours. Trust me, if you can make this approach work, it's worth it for the simplicity.

For (2), caching is also possible on the server side. You can use the same approach. Just cache a function call and let it expire with some time period.

**Active Expiration**

For (1), as you already noted, you can't avoid making an HTTP call to see what has changed. You have to make at the minimum, one call to see what might have changed. Your idea to hash entities would work fine.

For example, send over a list of hashes from the Android device to the company API call and it sends back *only updated* entities based on the hash.

For (2), it can be painful to pro-actively invalidate objects in a cache. I would keep only *one* instance of data in cache if you want to pro-actively invalidate/replace it. Otherwise it's hard to track down all instances and update/replace the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using one of the caching mechanisms already in use elsewhere on the web, such as the way you might handle caching of a css file for a website.  Two options for you:

- send a Last-Modified header with your data, indicating when this data last changed.  Save this and the response when you get it.  Then when you want to request the same data again, you can send the If-Modified-Since header with when your timestamp is from.  If it hasn't changed, your server sends 304 not modified and you use the cached data - otherwise, you get a new data set and Last-Modified header.
- Use an ETag, which is basically the same thing.  Generate a unique hash to go with each data set, then it will change if the data changes.

Both of those are standard and will be well documented and understood, so I'd recommend you research them to help you work out what is best for your application